# Using chrome.storage in Service Worker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I want to create an extension that relies on tracking the amount of tabs a user opens. From what I understand, the best way to do this with a background process is with a service worker that activates whenever a tab is created using the `tabs.onCreated` listener. However, whenever I try to `set` or `get` any type of `chrome.storage`, I am met with the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'local')`".

I'm not sure how to use chrome.storage, and I have read the [available docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/) and searched online for answers, with most of my service worker comprising of the example code on the Google Developer docs. My `manifest.json` and service worker are as follows:

manifest.json:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Tab Counter",
  "author": "CatRass",
  "description": "Count total amount of opened tabs",
  "version": "1.0",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "main.html",
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "storage"
    ]
  },  
  
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "js/background.js",
    "type": "module"
  }
}
```

background.js (Service Worker):

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.action.setBadgeText({
    text: "!",
  });
  chrome.storage.local.set({"tabsOpened":value});
});

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(() => {
  console.log("Tab Opened");
  
  chrome.storage.local.get(["tabsOpened"]).then((result) => {
    console.log("Value currently is " + result.key);
  });
  
});
```

Comment: Replace `result.key` with `result.tabsOpened`.

Comment: No bueno, code at background.js Line 8 (`chrome.storage.local.set`) causes error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'local')`, along with what you have mentioned, even when changing `result.key` to `result.tabsOpened`.

The issue is definitely not the `console.log`, but the `chrome.storage.local` itself, however I do think the change you recommended would have prevented a later error. Thank you!

Comment: The error message means that the extension doesn't have the "storage" permission. "But I gave it the 'storage' permission!", I can hear you say. You did, but not in the right place. [Manifest file format](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/)

Comment: I'm pleasantly surprised at not only your ability to read minds, but at how delicately and humorously you delivered that explanation. Thank you very much, and I'll be sure to refer to the correct Manifest file format from now on!